# How do I POST collection of data to controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following code to send DATA to controller action and return the plain HTML
I am getting empty object in controller action.

```
        var employees = [
                       { Title: "John", DataType: 1 },
                       { Title: "Anna", DataType: 2 },
                       { Title: "Peter", DataType: 3 }
    ];

    $("#btn-continueedit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // I tried post also here
            cache: false,
            url:'/user/UserinfoWizard',
               data: { values: employees }, 
            success: function (data) {

                $("#editUserInfo").html(data);

            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```

Here is my controller action

```
             [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult UserInfoWizard(List<UserInfoEditDetail> values)
            {
             // I get empty object 'values' here :( 
            }
```

Comment: Use `type: "POST"` and on the action `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting data in the client side ?

Comment: Also, the data passed to the post action should be an object: `data: { values: getSelectedAttributes() }`

Comment: i still get empty object in controller action even after suggested changes,

Comment: avinash, i can clearly see values in LOG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data passed with the ajax call should be an object containing the parameter which you want to use in the controller action. Your action expects a `values` parameter passed with the data, so your data object should be `data: { values: getSelectedAttributes() }`

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn-continueedit").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        //..
        data: { values: getSelectedAttributes() }, //Use the data object with values
        //..
    });
    return false; 
});
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserInfoWizard(object values) // parameter name should match the name passed in data object
{
   //..
}
```

**EDIT**

Indeed you action expects an object, while your values is an array. I don't know what the values are, but in your action you should have the `int[] values` or `string[] values` as parameter or any other array type you are expecting.

Comment: seems like getSelectedAttributes is not returning proper object

Comment: i tried hard coded value  data:{values: 'animal'}  it worked like charm.  it fails only when i try to send Array

Comment: how to define string array in client side?  var values = new Array();?

Comment: you don't have to define the type in JavaScript. Just push strings:
`var values = []; values.push("string");`

Comment: sorry! it did not work. still gives null. console is printing properly. i made action parameter as (string[] values).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn-continueedit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', // I tried post also here
            cache: false,
            dataType:JSON,
            url:'/user/UserinfoWizard',
            data: JSON.stringify({ data:getSelectedAttributes()}),
            success: function (data) {

                $("#editUserInfo").html(data);

            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```

**Updated:**

*When you are passing data during an ajax call, it should be in the form of an object and not an array*

Comment: when i changed to  var values = new Object(); it says object does not support 'push'

Comment: After creating the query , you should change it to an object as shown in above

Comment: not working, is there any way to make it json format so that i can access it

Comment: Avinash, my issue is how do we pass object collection so that , in controller I can get it like List<Employee>....  so in client side how can i send collection to data:, its not about sending single object, its collection of object